Cross-Report Drill-Through in Embedded Powerbi Report in Vue.JS Web Application
Is there a way to enable cross-report drill-through in an embedded powerbi report in Vue.JS web application. Both powerbi data source and target report are in the same powerbi workspace.
I want the target report for cross-report drill-through be added in the Drill Through option of my data source report same as the attached screenshot. I have tried modifying the menu commands in the report visual by adding extensions in the embed config of the powerbi report in JS. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

